# Instantiating a new PHP class with one or many arguments

Tags: php

I have this fetch function:

```
public static function fetch($class, $key)
{
    try
    {
        $obj = new $class($key);
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return $obj;
}
```

It creates a new instance by calling that class's constructor and passing in the key. Now, how would I make it so I can pass in an array of arguments in $key, and have it like:

```
$obj = new $class($key[0], $key[1]...);
```

So that it works for one or more keys?

Hopefully that was clear enough.

Using PHP 5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an interesting question.  If it wasn't a constructor function you were trying to give dynamic arguments to, then normally you could use [call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/call_user_func_array).  However, since the `new` operator is involved, there doesn't seem to be an elegant way to do this.

Reflection seems to be the consensus from what I could find.  The following snippet is taken from the user comments on [call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/call_user_func_array), and illustrates the usage quite nicely:

```
<?php

// arguments you wish to pass to constructor of new object
$args = array('a', 'b');

// class name of new object
$className = 'myCommand';

// make a reflection object
$reflectionObj = new ReflectionClass($className);

// use Reflection to create a new instance, using the $args
$command = $reflectionObj->newInstanceArgs($args);

// this is the same as: new myCommand('a', 'b');
?>
```

To shorten it up for your case, you can use:

```
$reflectionObject = new ReflectionClass($class);
$obj = $reflectionObject->newInstanceArgs($key);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [reflection](https://www.php.net/reflection):

```
$classReflection = new ReflectionClass($class);
$obj = $classReflection->newInstanceArgs($key);
```

Answer (score 2):

My [library](http://github.com/olliesaunders/fluidics) solves this [this](http://github.com/olliesaunders/fluidics/blob/master/lib/brown.php#L65):

```
// Returns a new instance of a `$classNameOrObj`.
function fuNew($classNameOrObj, $constructionParams = array()) {
    $class = new ReflectionClass($classNameOrObj);
    if (empty($constructionParams)) { return $class->newInstance(); }
    return $class->newInstanceArgs($constructionParams); }
```

The `empty()` test is required because `newInstanceArgs()` will complain if you give it an empty array, stupidly.

Answer (score 0):

What does the constructor of the class look like? Does it accept an arbitrary number of arguments? It might be better to accept an array of keys instead of a list of key arguments.

[`call_user_func_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) could probably do what you want:

```
$obj = new $object_class();
call_user_func_array(array($obj, '__construct'), $args);
```

Note that this calls the constructor twice, which could have negative side effects.

Comment: Also note this won't work for PHP4 code which uses the name of the class as the constructor's name instead of `__construct`.

Comment: Depends on the class, some are __construct($key) some are __construct($key1, $key2)